# How to Debug a package that required in Node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging

I have a app like this :

```
var q = require('something.js');
//other codes
```

and i save these codes in `test.js` file. for debuging `test.js` i know to use `node --debug-brk test` and then `nodeinspector` but how to debug `something.js` with data of `test.js` with node inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Step Into(F11)** when you are on the line that calls something using `q`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your app and what you are trying to do, you might be able to use this:
[Just My Code for JavaScript Windows Store Apps in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/19/just-my-code-for-javascript-windows-store-apps-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)